# Plot ellipse3d in R plotly?

Tags: r, plotly, rgl, r-plotly

Package `rgl` includes a very useful function `ellipse3d`, which can return an ellipsoid that cover like 95% percent of the points in 3D. Then this object can be used in `rgl::plot3d` to plot it out. My question is that is it possible to convert the output of `ellipse3d` to something that can be plotted through js plotting packages like plotly?

```
library(rgl)
dt <- cbind(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rnorm(100))
ellipse <- ellipse3d(cov(dt))
plot3d(dt)
plot3d(ellipse, add = T, color = "red", alpha = 0.5)
```

Then what can I do to plot the ellipsoid through plotly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extract the coordinates of the ellipse from the `ellipse$vb`.  Then plot these.  Something like:

```
p <- plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(type = 'scatter3d', size = 1, 
     x = ellipse$vb[1,], y = ellipse$vb[2,], z = ellipse$vb[3,], 
     opacity=0.01) %>% 
  add_trace(data=dt, type = 'scatter3d', x=~x, y=~y, z=~z)
```

[image]

Comment: awesome!! Thanks!

Comment: Note that for simplicity, I plotted the ellipse as a cloud using markers.  If you want to use `add_surface` instead, you will have to first convert the ellipse into a different format, with a vector of x locations, a vector of y locations, z as a matrix (dimensions equal to x by y).  You'll also need to split the z values into two separate surface layers one for the top half of the ellipsoid and one for the bottom.  I don't have time right now to do all this, but if you get stuck I can work this out later

Comment: Thank you again! I will give it a try. Sometime I feel like my two dimensional brain is not built for all these 3-d data processing. lol