# How do I plot a 3D surface and data points using plotly and R?

Tags: r, plotly

Using `plotly` and `R` I want to check that an ellipsoid is a good fit to the data points.

```
library(plotrix)
library(plotly)
library(Rvcg)
Library(rgl)

df_r_n_r = read.csv('temp.csv', header = TRUE)
fig <- plot_ly(df_r_n_r,type = "scatter3d", mode="markers", x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z)
fig

D <- rbind(c(459.956, -34.198, -29.844), c(-34.198, 481.647, 1.505), c(-29.844, 1.505, 559.393))
A <- D %*% t(D)
Am <- solve(A)
o <- c(73.658, 420.551, -429.058)
r <- 1

sphr <- vcgSphere()
ell <- scale3d(transform3d(sphr, chol(Am)), r, r, r)
vs <- ell$vb[1:3,] + o
idx <- ell$it - 1
e_plot <- plot_ly(type="mesh3d",
  x = vs[1,], y = vs[2,], z = vs[3,],
  i = idx[1,], j = idx[2,], k = idx[3,],
  opacity = 0.3)
```

I can plot the points using `fig` and the ellipsoid using `e_plot`, but how do I put them on the same plot so I can see how closely they fit.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51872043/3460670) that uses `add_trace` for `scatter3d` and `mesh3d` together --- does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `plot_ly`, you can combine a number of plots using the`add_trace` method. In the first instance, you can add the traces using the same parameters as you used to individually plot each item. In regard to the above question, this would produce:

```
    plot<- plot_ly()%>%
      add_trace(df_r_n_r,type = "scatter3d", mode="markers", x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z) %>%
      add_trace(type="mesh3d",x = vs[1,], y = vs[2,], z = vs[3,], idx[1,], j = idx[2,], k = idx[3,],opacity = 0.3)
   plot
```

Then you might want to vary the parameters in each trace to make the final plot clearer, e.g. change the opacity in the second plot.